# How to auto redirect to a page after successful ReCaptcha (I'm new to coding)

Tags: php, http, redirect

I am trying to automatically redirect the user to a [URL](http://www.theurl.com/) after the ReCaptcha was successful.

```
<?php
require('src/autoload.php');

$siteKey = 'my-site-key';
$secret = 'my-secret-key';

$recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($secret);

$gRecaptchaResponse = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']; //google captcha post data
$remoteIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //to get user's ip

$recaptchaErrors = ''; // blank varible to store error

$resp = $recaptcha->verify($gRecaptchaResponse, $remoteIp); //method to verify captcha
if ($resp->isSuccess()){
    header('Location: http://www.theurl.com/');  //this is where it should redirect to
    exit;
} 
else {
   $recaptchaErrors = $resp->getErrorCodes(); // set the error in varible
}
?>
```

I have searched almost the whole of Google to no avail.

Comment: `header('Location: http://www.theurl.com/');` is correct. You haven't actually described your issue in detail. Specifically what goes wrong? What debugging have you done?

Comment: Some debugging tips: If it isn't redirecting you then a) have you checked to ensure that the code is actually entering the `if ($resp->isSuccess()){` block? b) Have you checked the response coming back to the browser to see if it actually contains the Location header? (It's the _browser_ which actually performs the redirect - the PHP just sets a HTTP response header which tells it to do so). c) you're not running this via AJAX are you? Because an AJAX client won't honour a redirect request (since that kind of defeats the main purpose of AJAX).

Comment: Thank you @ADyson!
Sorry. The issue is that I want to - if the ReCaptcha is successfully ticked, redirect the page. I am a newby so I don't exactly know how to check if the code enters the    if ($resp->isSuccess()){   block. I'm using the standard ReCapcha code... Where will I see if it is AJAX? Sorry for all the stupid questions... Still learning here

Comment: The simplest way to do some quick debugging is with the [var_dump()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) command. This lets you see the values of variables, or just output some text so you know the code has reached a certain place. So in your case to test, you could temporarily write `if ($resp->isSuccess()){
    var_dump("success");
    //header('Location: http://www.theurl.com/');  //this is where it should redirect to
    exit;
} else { var_dump("fail");
   $recaptchaErrors = $resp->getErrorCodes(); // set the error in varible
} `

Comment: That should then show on screen if the code is entering the if block, or the else block

Comment: P.S. You'd know if you're using AJAX by the way you submit the form from your browser. If you simply created a `<form>` tag and a submit button, and no further code, then you're doing a conventional postback. Whereas if you wrote some JavaScript (possibly with fetch() or $.ajax() for XmlHttpRequest) to make the call to your PHP URL, and your page does not fully refresh afterwards, then that would be an [AJAX call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started)

Comment: Ok so here's a short version...

Comment: er...were you intending to say more than that??